# laravel Many To Many relationship with inner relation

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, relationship

I have some problem to get information about item. I read a lot of information on forums stakoverflow. Maybe i can not find the correct information. Maybe someone knows about that hove to solve the problem
I have 4 tables

```
    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('db_items', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

---

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('db_item_weapons', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('item_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('item_id')
                ->references('id')->on('db_items')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->integer('grade_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('grade_id')
                ->references('id')->on('db_item_grades')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->string('hand')->nullable();
            $table->string('name')->nullable();
            $table->text('description')->nullable();
            $table->string('icon')->nullable();
            $table->string('p_atak')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

---

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('db_item_categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

---

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('db_item_db_item_category', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('item_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('item_id')
            ->references('id')->on('db_items')
            ->onDelete('cascade');


$table->integer('category_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->foreign('category_id')
                ->references('id')->on('db_item_categories')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

---

And 3 models

```
class DbItem extends Model
{
    function weapon()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(DbItemWeapon::class, 'item_id');
    }

    function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(DbItemCategory::class,'db_item_db_item_category','item_id','category_id');
    }
}
```

---

```
class DbItemWeapon extends Model
{
    function DbItem()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(DbItem::class);
    }

}
```

---

```
class DbItemCategory extends Model
{
    function items()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(DbItem::class,'db_item_db_item_category','category_id','item_id')->with('weapon');
    }
}
```

---

When i try to get some inforamtion it wotrks for example

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
 <li>
   <a class="uk-accordion-title" href="#">{{ $category->name }}</a>
      <div class="uk-accordion-content">
         @foreach( $category->items as $item)
            <p>{{ $item->id }}</p>
         @endforeach
      </div>
 </li>
@endforeach
```

i got the categories wtith their items and i can view the items id which contains in categoryes but if i want to see more information, its not work
$item->weapon->name

Comment: So if I am understanding correctly `{{ $item->id }}` works but `{{ $item->weapon->name }}` does not.

What happens when you try to output `{{ $item->weapon->name }}`? Do you get an error? Is it just blank?

Try outputting `{{ dd($item->weapon) }}` to see what you get.

Comment: post your controller method that sends $item variable to blade view please.

Comment: @Tony i added the dd() and i got the all inforamtion theier i have all atributes of the items but i cant to withdraw it to view `{{ $item->weapon->name }}` give an error Trying to get property 'name' of non-object

Comment: @Polaris `class DataBaseController extends Controller { public function index() { $categories = DbItemCategory::all(); return view('database.index')->withCategories($categories); } }`

Comment: User this in your controller to get categories; `$categories = DbItemCategory::with('items.weapon')->all();`

Comment: @ako not works :(

Comment: Does the item definitely have a weapon in the database i.e. have you doubled checked that the item id has a matching `item_id`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe some of the `items` does not have a `weapon`, check for the `weapon's` existence first:

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
 <li>
   <a class="uk-accordion-title" href="#">{{ $category->name }}</a>
      <div class="uk-accordion-content">
         @foreach( $category->items as $item)
            @php
                $weapon = $item->weapon;
            @endphp
            <p>{{ $item->id }}</p>
            <p>{{ $weapon ? $weapon->name : null }}</p>
         @endforeach
      </div>
 </li>
@endforeach
```

Comment: yes it helps, thaks. I founded 1 item that do not have weapon

Comment: @RolandVerner Absolutely the problem is with that item.